# FFMPEG: Terminal: Output name included original file ending ".mov" in output title: How to remove

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, command-line

I successfully outputted the desired effect for my FFMPEG command. I had been removing the audio from my videos with this line of code:

```
 for i in *.mov; do ffmpeg -i $i -c:v copy -an $i-noaudio.mp4; done
```

The output results as "myInputvideo.mov-noaudio.mp4"

How might I get this to output without the ".mov" in the title?
And how might I move all these outputs into a new directory entitled "no-audio"

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use Parameter/Variable Expansion. instead of `$i`, use `${i%.mov}` as follows:

Note: I replaced the variable `i` with `file`, for clarity.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.mov; do
  ffmpeg -i ${file} -c:v copy -an ${file%.mov}-noaudio.mp4
done
```

Here is a good reference for Variable Expansion: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html